# What does ::struct mean in this context?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I don't know how to search for this, as it seems google ignores the `::` in my search.

I have the following line in pseudo code:
(player in this context is defined as: `Player *player`)

```
if ( player == ::player )
```

I am taking this to mean, if `var player`, is of type `player`. But that doesn't make sense to me as the compiler should know what type it is.

> So what does `::player` mean here?

Comment: Any resources on this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment. So turned it into a full answer.

Typically the `::` operator is used as a [Scope resolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator).

Depending on the language, in your example because there is no prepended namespace, it would refer to the global `player`

*From the linked page:*

```
class A {
public:
    static int i; // scope of A
};

namespace B {
    int j = 2;
}  // namespace B

int A::i = 4;  // scope operator refers to the integer i declared in the class A
int x = B::j;  // scope operator refers to the integer j declared in the namespace B
```

In the context of IDA, it could be it's own way of referencing a global `player` object.

So in your example:

```
if ( player == ::player )
```

The developer is explicitly forcing the local `player` object / variable to be compared to the `player` object/variable that is in the global namespace.

Here is a a [simple online demo](https://ideone.com/lWSu5c) that might help. The `avar` primitive variable could be a more complex object, class or function instead of an int.

Comment: Hm, I'd guess it's checking if the player the function was called on, is the local player (local as in, not an online player). The thing that threw me off, was that there was no type name, so I wasn't sure about it.

Comment: I updated the answer with a simple online demo app that might also help.